# dc.js stackable bar - interleaved display issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

Here is my [bar chart](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwYxA85P9A4mbFVGbHNERWFNVUE) and [json file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwYxA85P9A4mcnlsQzJyTVczMWs), based on the [example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/stacked-bar.html) found in the dc.js.

The  x-axis is time and I am grouping them at 15 minutes interval, y-axis is count. 
The chart is rendering but noticed that the *'stacked area'* is [interleaved](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwYxA85P9A4mbmx3UDk3Zzg1RWc).

Could you please help me find the reason for this behavior? Thanks